# Error al compilar Nodejs con multer

Tags: nodejs, multer

Hago la subida de imagenes con `multer`,y funciona, pero cuando quiero compilar Nodejs con `npm run build`, por consola muestra el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por las dudas les dejo el codigo completo:

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callBack) => {
        //carpeta donde va a guardar las imgs
        callBack(null, 'uploads') 
    },
    filename: (req, file, callBack) => {
        // uuid.v4() guarda la img con id aleatorio, para que no
        // se pisen imagenes en el caso que se suban con el mismo nombre
        callBack(null, uuid.v4() + path.extname(file.originalname).toLocaleLowerCase());
    }    
})

const upload = multer({
    storage,
    dest: 'uploads/',
    //dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/uploads'),
    limits: {fileSize: 2000000}, //max permitido de image, 2 mega byte de peso
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        const fileTypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;   // expresion regular
        // mimetype checkea si el archivo es valido ej img/extension del archivo
        const mimetype = fileTypes.test(file.mimetype);
        // con path.extname checkea si la img tiene la extension .jpeg o .jpg o .gif o .png
        const extname = fileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname));
        if(mimetype && extname){
            return cb(null, true);
        }
        else{
            cb("Error: el archivo debe ser una imagen valida");
        }
    }
}).single('file');


app.post('/file', upload, (req, res, next) => {
    //en esta linea marca el error
    const file = req.file;
    console.log(file);
    if(!file){
        console.log('No se subió ninguna imagen');
    }
    res.send(file);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado!, la solución fue poner esta linea de código `const file = (req as any).file;`

```js
app.post('/file', upload, (req, res, next) => {
   
    const file = (req as any).file;
    console.log(file);
    if(!file){
        console.log('No se subió ninguna imagen');
    }
    res.send(file);
  })
```